# How to convert column dataframe in pandas into time

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, datetime-format

I need to make a plot but I got this error:

```
 TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

I then tried to to convert the column belonging to the x axis into time, but I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

This is my code and below my dataframe. Any help is welcome

```
#import
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'results.xlsx', 'growth')
df1_sub = df1.groupby(["Sampling", ], as_index=False).agg({'NPQ':['mean', 'std']})
df1_sub.columns = ['Sampling','NPQ','std']

# here I try to make the conversion
df1_sub['Sampling'] = pd.to_datetime(df1_sub['Sampling'])

#plotting

ax1.errorbar('Sampling', 'NPQ', yerr='std', data=df1_sub)
plt.show()
```

My dataframe in excel looks like this:

```
 x              y
 14:00:00 AM    15
 15:00:00 AM    345
 16:00:00 AM    25
```

Comment: is `df1_sub['Sampling']` the same as `x` column from your example?

Comment: @MrFuppes yes it is

Comment: your time column x has values in 24h format but also has "AM" suffix, that is not correct time value.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran thanks. How can I remove the "AM"?

Comment: dump a reproducible example, something like `df.to_dict()` that makes much easier for people here to help you

Comment: @moth if I write print(df.to_dict()) I get the same error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Comment: I think when you load the df from Excel, the time column (Excel) is converted to `datetime.time` (pandas df). You could try `df1_sub['Sampling'] = pd.to_datetime(df1_sub['Sampling'].astype(str))`. It will add a default date.

Comment: use this to drop the AM/PM suffixes from your time column, like so `df['x']=df['x'].str.replace('.M','',case=False,regex=True)`, instead of x use your column name.

Comment: also, you are using ax1.errorbar, I think you meant to do `plt.errorbar`

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran thank you. I tried your code and I got this message: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: try to print this value and see what data type is that `type(df1_sub['Sampling'][0])`

Comment: @MrFuppes your suggestion worked, thanks. Now I get '2021-11-18 06:15:00' Do you you know also how can I drop date and cut the time to only hours and minutes?

Comment: If you use the pandas datetime data type (which I recommend), you'll always have the date. For a plot, I'd suggest to use a formatter so that only the time is displayed.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, column 'Sampling' is <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: @MrFuppes, very helpful!